# Error 500 with Laravel 5.4 on Nginx and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

I'm getting error 500 server internal error with Laravel 5.4 on Nginx and Ubuntu 16.04.

First I found out `display_error` was `off` in php-fpm configuration. Then after solving this issue still Laravel has the same problem.

I'm sure `storage` and `bootstrap` folder is writable.

To ensure what is this error for, I checked Laravel `index.php` file. This line is causing 500 error:

```
$response->send();
```

Comment: are you using a controller to display the page or just a view?  Is this a new project or something you have already developed?

Comment: you have to set write permission for bootstrap/cache folder also

Comment: @RavishaHesh bootstrap folder is also writable

Comment: Look inside `storage/logs` to know why.

Comment: @AndyKillen It's an already developed project. I just moved the project to a new server with almost the same configuration. The only change is control panel which was Webmin and now is ISPConfig.

Comment: As @MarcoAurélioDeleu said you should be able to identify the error from storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Same as everyone else is saying.  Check that Laravel/the server, can write to the various directories, such as /storage/* and /bootstrap/cache

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu It's empty!

Comment: @AndyKillen I'm sure these folders are writable.

Comment: Then look inside Nginx error log, usually, it's `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: @RavishaHesh It's also almost empty and there is no Laravel related logs in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Just a couple of error which are related to ISPConfig.

Comment: If it's a laravel error it must show on `storage/logs/laravel.log`. It's empty because the error occurs from the server settings. So you should try to identify the error from nginx log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very suddenly I run `php artisan config:clear` and it solved the problem. It seems there was an error in configs.